# How to sync groups from Google Workspace to Microsoft Entra ID (formerly Azure AD)

Tags: azure-active-directory, google-workspace

We are using Google Workspace as a source of truth for all our users and groups, and would like to synchronize our Microsoft Entra ID (formerly Azure AD) tenant with users and groups from Google Workspace.

We've already [configured federation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/education/windows/configure-aad-google-trust) between Google Workspace and Microsoft Entra ID, and users are being synced using [Microsoft Office 365 auto-provisioning](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7365072#zippy=%2Cset-up-auto-provisioning-for-the-microsoft-office-application). Our Google Workspace users can log into Office 365/azure just fine, however we would like to use Azure AD groups for permissions etc.

The problem is that that doesn't sync user groups, Google also doesn't seem to be much help here. Has anyone have idea how is this normally achieved?

Thanks!

*Note: The sync direction we are after is **(from) Google workspace** -> **(to) Microsoft Entra ID**. There's bunch of ways doing this the other way around (like GCDS), but that's not applicable in our case.*

Comment: Check this https://cloud.google.com/architecture/identity/federating-gcp-with-azure-ad-configuring-provisioning-and-single-sign-on